# iTunes search JSON API returning 403 forbidden on server

Tags: app-store, itunes

For the six weeks or so, we have been able to execute queries against the iTunes search JSON API without issue. Starting this week, we started to see 403 errors after a certain number of requests (about 1K - 2K). We're assuming this is a rate-limiting issue, perhaps a new policy they implemented. Is there another explanation we're overlooking?

Comment: We also experienced massive 403 from Apple iTunes RSS feed starting from 4th June, not sure if it is related to WWDC

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As you are looking to get price and ratings my guess is that you are doing a lookup, not a search, with the iTunes Search API.

If that assumption is true then you can "batch" lookup requests by listing multiple ADAM IDs in a query by separating them with a comma.

eg. To get results for both of these apps in the US --

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/9-innings-2013-pro-baseball/id530061728?mt=8

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/homerun-battle-2-free/id491221570?mt=8

-- you'd do this: 
https://itunes.apple.com/us/lookup?id=491221570,530061728

I believe the limit is 50 ids per query.

If there are [approximately 900K apps currently live in the App Store](http://148apps.biz/app-store-metrics/), some quick math shows that before batching, if you evenly spread out your requests you'd be doing ~625 queries / minute.  (900K / 24 hours / 60 minutes == 625)

However, if you batch them in groups of 50 then you are looking at about 13 queries / minute
(900K / 50 per request / 24 hours / 60 minutes == 12.5).  This should be well within the allowed limit.

...@Crashalot - if you are doing app recommendations, then we should talk.

Comment: This sounds like a really good strategy, i'll have to try this too.

Comment: The limit is actually 200 per query, but the 403 issue isn't related to this. The 403 error is returned even for queries with one id, Apple might be enforcing stricter rules on the number of HTTP requests that can be made to the search API

Comment: I just ran into this problem recently, they accept 200 ids per query and you only have to send 5000 queries to Apple server which should not exceed their limit.

Comment: @Cat I have succeed with more than 200 per query.

Comment: @northtree how many did you manage to fit in one query?

Comment: @Cat I got results for over 300+ per query. But I could figure out the limit.

Comment: @Cat maybe the limit you are experiencing is coming from your client? 200 ids would make the query string over 2000 characters which might be causing issues?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's any *published* rate limits, but I think it's pretty safe to assume they do exist. What's the timescale for the 1-2k of requests you're running - minutes, hours, days?

Apple do recommend you implement caching to prevent needless queries. If you're not doing this already then you should probably look into it. Another option is to use the [enterprise partner feed](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-enterprise-partner-feed.html), although you need to be an iTunes affiliate to gain access.

Comment: it's minutes. we definitely cache when possible, but one of the things we need is the app's price, which may change daily. the only way to check is to fetch every app's price each day. do you see another option for us? thanks!

Comment: @Crashalot - have you attempted spreading the load across several hours?  Are you blasting all your requests at the same time every day?

Comment: hi @TedHosmann. we're trying to help people discover great apps from indie devs -- not necessarily the most popular ones. we can see that you work in the itunes affiliate group and would love your input. what's the sanctioned way to get rating data? it's not in the EPF files. we're only resorting to the JSON API because it seems like this is the only way to fetch rating data. we can happily spread the load across several hours or change when the script runs if that is the approved way to fetch rating data.

Comment: @Crashalot Not sure I know how to solve this specific issue - I don't have as much experience trying to collect info on *every* app in the catalog.  Sounds like the Search API may not be the right tool.  Please post your findings if you resolve this issue.

Comment: thanks @TedHosmann. we tried emailing someone in your group about advice on the sanctioned method to fetch rating data, but no one responded. would you mind asking someone in your group?